# ViewPager slide to next page when imageView onclick

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a question on ViewPager slide to next page when imageView onclick
Currently, I have 2 pages of ViewPager, and each of them has a different layout
I made a button on first_frag.xml, and try to set onClick Listener to the FirstFragment class, but it doesn't work, any help? Here attached my sources:

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
public ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        switch(pos) {

        case 0: return FirstFragment.newInstance("First Page");
        case 1: return SecondFragment.newInstance("Second Page");
        default: return FirstFragment.newInstance("Default");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }       
}
}
```

---

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_frag, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragFirst);
    tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));
    return v;

}


public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;

}
```

---

**SecondFragment.java**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);

TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));


return v;
}

public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("msg", text);

f.setArguments(b);

return f;

}


}
```

---

**first_frag.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TestString"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Testing String"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFragFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="26dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thisButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/nextPage"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
   </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

---

**second_frag.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFragSecond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="42dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: i cant see any button here

Comment: @WasimAhmed The imageView is the button in first_frag

Answer (score 1):

// **Fragment 1:**

```
View v;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_frag, container, false);

TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragSecond);
tv.setText(getArguments().getString("msg"));

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thisButton);
            iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                       public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity mActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity():
            mActivity.changeFragment();

                }
           });
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public void changeFragment(){
pager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

What I did was:

- Set a listener for the imageView inside the fragment onCreateView
- Add a public method to the main activity, called changeFragment, which sets the current viewPager item.
- Call this method from the listener.

Comment: just tried, but it force closes :/
E/AndroidRuntime(26857):at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)